# d3 version 4, I'm trying to make a mouseover conditional based on class

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make this mouseover conditional. if the "selected" class exists then return the mouseover function
This is the code:

```
.on("mouseover", function() { if(d3.select(this).classed("selected")) {
return ""}
else{
return mouseover}
})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to *call* the `mouseover` function depending on the class. If that is correct, you just need to do:

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
    if (d3.select(this).classed("selected")) {
        mouseover()
    }
 })
```

Or, alternatively:

```
selection.selectAll(".selected").on("mouseover", mouseover)
```

Here is a demo. The first circle doesn't have the class, the second one does:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([1, 1])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 100 + 100 * i
  })
  .classed("selected", function(d, i) {
    return i
  })
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    if (d3.select(this).classed("selected")) {
      mouseover()
    }
  })

function mouseover() {
  console.log("mouse over")
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: I want the mouse over to work on lines that do not have the class "selected"  so from what you posted it works for me except on the first occurrence, I get an error. this is what i'm using:   .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                                if (d3.select(this).classed("line selected")) {
                                                return " "} else {mouseover(d)
                                }
                    })

Comment: In that case, just invert the boolean: `if (!d3.select(this).classed("selected")){mouseover()}`. Also, my code cannot throw any error, so I don't know what error are you talking about.